# Using vertex array, quad array to create mesh of quad

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl, mesh, vertex

I'm doing `OpenGL` program and I'm required to create a user defined dimension quad mesh.

From what I understand so far is that I use array of vertices to draw quads that actually will form quad meshes. It's pretty simple concept but I'm having a tough time understanding it.

So please correct me if I understand it incorrectly.

So if a user wants to do a 4x4 mesh, there will be 16 quads all together and 64 vertices to place them. 
So as user defines the resolution of mesh (oh by the way, the boundary size is already given at the beginning), I create those 64 vertices.

Am I getting it correct so far?

I'm going to interact with those quads and reshaped them to form a mountain kinda shapes.

Of course i would need bigger resolution probably 32x32 or even bigger to properly display such thing.

Comment: Do these quads form one big quad? EG, would a 2x2 look like a foursquare court?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to make a mesh of quads that in turn creates one big quad.

It would look something like this for a 4x4

```
 _ _ _ _
|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|
```

In this case you would only need (4+1)x(4+1) vertices, so 25 vertices. You could specify the four vertices of each quad uniquely, although aside from being unnecessary for a mesh (and wasting memory and speed), it might end up being harder for you to add that "mountain" functionality (something like a terrain I'm guessing). If you move a vertex in the middle of the mesh, you probably want it to move for all four quads that use that vertex. If you have the quads **share vertices** (as they do in a mesh), moving one point would change all the quads using that point.

Basically, specify all the unique vertices and connect them as quads. Redundancy is best avoided.

Also, if you're learning OpenGL, make sure you're not learning with the fixed function pipeline (if you have a `glBegin()` or a `glVertex3f()` in there, you're using the fixed function pipeline). There are far too many reasons why you shouldn't use it (it's decades old, it's slower, it's not nearly as flexible), but perhaps the biggest reason is that it's a waste of time if you want to do real graphics. You'd have to learn how to use the programmable pipeline, and having fixed function pipeline habits and ways of thinking in your head will only make it harder than it has to be.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I've just started working on it and it guided me to right direction! I've used old functions as first assinment, just to draw subdivision curves and playing around with them - transforming, rotating that kind of stuff. it's very challenging for me but i'm very positive i can do it!

Comment: so the array of vertices would be just vertices[] = {0, 3, ...}? would that be sufficent to hold all the vertices for my mesh? the requirement is 32x32 or 64x64 and I'm dropping a blobbly object and position them using gaussian blobs and smooth shading

Comment: Don't define them statically (too much work!) - generate them based on the dimensions of your quad. They'd end up looking like (0,0),(1,0),(2,0)...(0,1),(1,1),(2,1)...(n,n). Then you can define the vertices of each quad through indices into this array, which you should also generate.

Comment: "I suggest you create a C file (or a C++ class) that has the following functions (or
methods if you’re using a class):
a. allocateMesh(int dim1, dim2) // e.g. 64X64 or 32X32 etc etc, allocate
vertex array and quad array memory
b. initializeMesh(originX, originZ, xWidth, zWidth) // construct vertex array
and quad array"

This is part of guideline my prof gave. what do u think originX and Z are for in initializeMesh function?

Comment: If you have another question, best to finish this one up and ask a new one. Comments aren't good for asking for clarifications or very very brief followup questions, not for new questions.